# Usar ponto ou vírgula em número flutuante?

Tags: c#, sintaxe, números, literal

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença de uma operação matemática com um número com virgula e outro com ponto.

Exemplo:

```
var altura = 1,83
```

Ou

```
var altura = 1.83
```

Qual deles é o correto?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

Nenhuma das duas linhas está correta porque em ambas falta `;` para finalizar o *statement* que é uma declaração de uma variável e atribuição de um valor do tipo `double`.

É `double` porque usa `var` que indica para o compilador que o tipo deve ser definido pelo valor que está atribuindo para a variável sendo declarada. E o valor atribuído é um literal do tipo `double` porque se convencionou que sempre que um literal numérico tiver uma parte decimal e nenhum sufixo para indicar o tipo então o tipo é `double`.

O primeiro é mais errado porque essa sintaxe com `,` não é aceita, basta escrever, tentar compilar e resultará em erro. Assim como a linguagem de programação é toda em inglês, o padrão adotado para separador decimal é o `.`, e não o que estamos acostumados aqui no Brasil.

A vírgula é usada para separar expressões em alguns contextos, mas essa não está separando expressões. Se o compilador aceitasse isso como uma lista de expressões usando a vírgula, então a última seria a prevalente e descartaria as demais, portanto o valor atribuído seria 83, e o tipo da variável seria `int` por não ter parte decimal. Mas por "sorte" o compilador nem aceita isso.

Comment: Muito obrigado Maniero pela explicação! Abraço

Comment: @JJB veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado quando uma resposta atendeu o que queria. Pode marcar com aceita e votar na resposta.